# Creating a binary variable based on the median of another variable, grouping by two variables

Tags: group-by, binary, stata, median, dummy-variable

In Stata I would like to create a binary variable `median_unemp` based on the median value of another variable `unemp`, grouping the calculation of the median value by `region` and `year`. That is, `median_unemp`is 1 when the unemployment for that particular observation is greater than the median unemployment for the region and the year of the observation (and is 0 otherwise).

The code below generates my variable considering the entire dataset, but I want the median to be calculated by subgroups (by `region` and `year`):

```
webuse productivity.dta, clear
summarize unemp, detail
gen median_response = r(p50)
gen median_unemp = (unemp>=median_response)
replace median_unemp =. if unemp==.
```

On closer inspection of the data, I would like to know if `unemp`for observation 1 of my dataset (that is in `region`=1 and `year`=1970) is greater than the value of `median_unemp` (calculated for `region`=1 and `year`=1970) and so on. If it is greater than the median, then `median_unemp`==1. If it is lower than the median, then `median_unemp`==0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
webuse productivity.dta, clear
egen median_unemp = median(unemp), by(region year)
gen high_unemp = (unemp >= median_unemp) if unemp < .
```

In this dataset, there are no missing values for `unemp` but separating missings is good practice. Each median is the 5th of 9 values, so setting aside ties 4 values will be less than the median and 5 more than or equal to the median.